# BASH - grep ps data that has sequence/incremented numbers

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a bash for loop that iterates through a list of processes from ps.  The idea is to see if the process is running and count the output.  An example list to be iterated through is below

```
BOX.Container_Philips1_Primary_X1
BOX.Container_Philips_Primary_X1
BOX.Container_Philips3_Primary_X1
BOX.Container_Server1_X1
BOX.Container_Node1_X1
BOX.Container_Host1_X1
BOX.Container_ClockService1_X1
BOX.Container_ClockService2_X1
```

my bash code is as follows

```
#PSUEDO
procs=(
Philips 1
Node 1 
Host 1 
Server 1
Philips1 1
Philips3 1 
ClockService 2)
#END PSUEDO

for (( i=0 ; i<"${#procs[@]}" ; i++ ))
do
  name=$(echo "${procs[i]}" | awk '{print $1}')
  configured_count=$(echo "${procs[i]}" | awk '{print $2}')

  running=()
  while read -r line
  do
    running+=("${line}")
  done < <(ps -u user -f | grep "BOX.${name}" | grep -v grep)

  if [[ "${configured_count}" -gt "${#running[@]}" ]]; then
    result+=$(echo -e "\n[FAIL] ${name} - configured count: ${configured_count} running count: ${#running[@]}")
  elif [[ "${#running[@]}" -gt "${configured_count}" ]]; then
    result+=$(echo -e "\n[WARN] ${name} - configured count: ${configured_count} running count: ${#running[@]}")
  else
    result+=$(echo -e "\n[PASS] ${name} - configured count: ${configured_count} running count: ${#running[@]}")
  fi
done
```

When iterating, name=Philips will return a count of 3 (wrong), name=Philips1 or Philips3; count of 1 (desired).  I need some ideas on how to handle the Philips lines, but not mis-count the 'Host', 'Node' entries.  From an architecture standpoint, the Philips processes are distinct, whereas ClockService for example is load balanced.  I want to say that ClockService has a count of 2, but each Philips should have a count of 1.

Comment: Could could search for `${name}_` - that would mean that when name is Philips it won't match Philips1.  You would then need to have a name of `ClockService.` (with the `.`) to merge the two `ClockService` lines

Comment: @StephenHarris, I edited my code block to hopefully better explain the full context of what I am trying to do

Comment: I don't think your array/loop is doing what you think it is: you've got an indexed array with elements `Philips`, `1`, `Node`, `1` and so on. Probably what you want is a *associative* array `declare -A procs=( [Philips]=1 [Node]=1  [Host]=1  [Server]=1 [Philips1]=1 [Philips3]=1  [ClockService]=2)` which you can then iterate over as `for i in "${!procs[@]}"; do name="$i"; configured_count="${procs[$i]}"; done`

Comment: `name=$(echo ... | awk ...)` is a travesty.  You're not really using the array, so just write the outer loop as `cat << EOF |\nPhilips 1\nNode 1\n...\nEOF\nwhile read name configured_count; do ....`

Comment: Please provide some sample output based upon the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the input and comments from all.  One additional element to the input I failed to mention is a prefix that separates the types of process, so they are not just all "BOX".  Example ps input

```
BOX.CC_Container_Philips1_Primary_X1
BOX.CC_Container_Philips_Primary_X1
BOX.CC_Container_Philips3_Primary_X1
BOX.Container_Server1_X1
BOX.Container_Node1_X1
BOX.Container_Host1_X1
BOX.Container_ClockService1_X1
BOX.Container_ClockService2_X1
```

so what I ended up doing is writing a conditional based on the type (is it "CC" or not?) and then running separate loops on that.  May not be the best method, but it works.

```
#name = list of process names from SQL, parsed into an array
type=$(echo "${name}" | awk -F"_" '{print $1}')
if [[ "${type}" == "CC" ]]; then
while read -r line
do
  running+=("${line}")
done < <(ps -u esmadmin -f | grep "${DOMAIN}.${name}_" | grep -v grep)
else 
  while read -r line
  do
  running+=("${line}")
done < <(ps -u esmadmin -f | grep "${DOMAIN}.${name}" | grep -v grep)
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to build a `grep` pattern that matches more closely what you want.  Remember that `.` matches any character.

So, for example, `BOX.Container_${name}_` becomes a useful pattern.  Now `Philips` is distinct from `Philips1`.  Where you want to merge entries you can search for `ClockService.`; that will merge `ClockService1` and `ClockService2`.

We can also simplify some of the tests with `grep -c` and use `[B]OX` to avoid the `grep -v` requirement.

So the resulting code looks something like:

```
declare -A procs=(
[Philips]=1
[Node.]=1 
[Host.]=1 
[Server.]=1
[Philips1]=1
[Philips3]=1 
[ClockService.]=2)

# psout=$(ps -u user -f)
psout=$(cat psout)

for i in "${!procs[@]}"
do
  name=$i
  configured_count=${procs[$i]}

  running=$(echo "$psout" | grep -c "[B]OX.Container_${name}_")

  if [[ "$configured_count" -gt "$running" ]]; then
    result+=$(echo -e "\n[FAIL] ${name} - configured count: ${configured_count} running count: $running")
  elif [[ "$running" -gt "$configured_count" ]]; then
    result+=$(echo -e "\n[WARN] ${name} - configured count: ${configured_count} running count: $running")
  else
    result+=$(echo -e "\n[PASS] ${name} - configured count: ${configured_count} running count: $running")
  fi
done

echo "$result"
```

In this example, I'm `cat`ting the file rather than calling `ps`, but you can see how to change this.

```
% cat psout
BOX.Container_Philips1_Primary_X1
BOX.Container_Philips_Primary_X1
BOX.Container_Philips3_Primary_X1
BOX.Container_Server1_X1
BOX.Container_Node1_X1
BOX.Container_Host1_X1
BOX.Container_ClockService1_X1
BOX.Container_ClockService2_X1

% bash code

[PASS] Node. - configured count: 1 running count: 1
[PASS] ClockService. - configured count: 2 running count: 2
[PASS] Philips1 - configured count: 1 running count: 1
[PASS] Philips3 - configured count: 1 running count: 1
[PASS] Server. - configured count: 1 running count: 1
[PASS] Philips - configured count: 1 running count: 1
[PASS] Host. - configured count: 1 running count: 1
```